# DPDK Compilation fails inside WSL2 Docker Desktop's containers

Tags: wsl-2, dpdk

I can't compile DPDK inside a docker container, running under WSL2 as VM (and windows 10 as the host machine).

**Background**

Trying to compile DPDK locally inside a wsl-container some DPDK lib that used to be built on remote native linux machines.

The Dockerfile running the compilation had installed `kernel headers`, `GNU toolchain` and other various dependencies. The distribution is `CentOS7`.

The containers are managed by Docker Desktop

Versions are useless information here.

**The Problem**

Similar problems across DPDK versions.
In DPDK 20.11, using the `meason` build-system, the file `kernel/linux/meason.build`:

`../kernel/linux/meson.build:23:1: ERROR: Problem encountered: Cannot compile kernel modules as requested - are kernel headers installed?`

If I compile different DPDK versions of DPDK or building using other build-systems (makefiles), I am getting variants of the same error.

Comment: from your question you state you are using HOST as Centos, while running Docker for `Windows`. is that the right understanding? or is your statement `I am using Host centos and VM (guest) as windows10 server`? Can you please clarify? One needs `windows 10 server` and `kernel module for Windows is netuio and not ugb_uio`. Can you please update with information.

Comment: I just mean the distribution I am running for WSL is Centos7.
Windows is the general env (of course), the distribution used with the microsoft kernel is Centos7. The containers are also centos7 based (FROM centos7)

Comment: The docker desktop sees all images I am creating inside WSL2, so I can use docker package coming with centos7 or docker desktop interchangeably. There are some slightest issues running each one (drive mapping for example, creating the build context and etc)

Comment: Didn't understand the line `kernel module for Windows is netuio and not ugb_uio`, sorry

Comment: can you clarify you have windows 10 server as host and you are trying to run centos as VM using WSL? If yes, the error you are facing is related to `missing kernel headers` for centos. Once you installed kernel headers for centos you build igb_uio driver for centos. (note: for windows driver is netuio, that requires windows 10 server environment) Please let me know what is your environment?

Comment: @VipinVarghese,
1. win10 = host, centos as VM. correct.
2. This is similar but slightly different. The kernel headers in the VM is actualy a softlink between "5.1-windowsXXX" kernel (uname -r output) -> "3.10-XXX.x86_64". 
3. This soft link is *not* present in running containers. If you keep your VM clean and want to use only containers for DPDK compilation, you will install `kernel headers` only on the container. But that doesn't have the aforementioned softlink and compilation will fail
4. This is really a stupid problem when you understand it, I feel little ashamed to put it in SO :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I was confused because WSL is light weight layer which allows you run Linux application from windows Host. So when you stated `WSL-Container in windows env` It got confusing. From your current explanation, you use windows host to run VM for centos, then you use container inside centos for building DPDK. If this is true, yes one needs to give access to docker for building igb_uio.ko, rte_kni.ko. WSL is windows substytem layer, hence correct question was misleading for me.

Comment: @VipinVarghese
ill edit the question later to follow your clarifications, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/lib/modules` There is no entry with WSL2 "uname -r" output.

Although WSL2 has `/lib/modules/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2` (as a softlink), this soft link does not appear in the container.

The solution is adding this line to the `Dockerfile`*:

```
RUN ln -s /lib/modules/$(ls /lib/modules/) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

*(This assumes only one entry is found on `/lib/modules` and that `/usr/src/kernels` exists for that entry.)

Another solution (I didn't test) is to run the container:

```
docker run --name test  -v /usr/src/kernels:/usr/src/kernels and -v /lib/modules/:lib/modules -dt image-name
```

Assuming your host has installed kernel-headers and that they can be found (i.e., `/usr/src/kernels/XXX/` is found and `/lib/modules/XXX/build` softlink is not broken)